# Role/Grammar of 找 and 跟 in "他找白如玉跟他在師大附近走走"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 他找白如玉跟他在師大附近走走, 試試地圖好用不好用。

My book translates this as:

> He went to see Bai Ruyu and asked her to accompany him on a walk around NTNU to try out the map functions.

This is how my English brain is breaking the sentence down
[他找白如玉 - he looks for Bai Ruyu] (跟他 - with him) (在師大附近走走 - near shida walks)

Confused how "asked her" is included in the Chinese? Also confused how the three above parts link together logically.

Comment: 找 in this case does not necessarily mean 'look for' in this case, and it is independent of 跟. It means more like 'get/ask somebody (to do sth)'. The sentence basically means he 'asked Bai Ruyu to do sth' and the 'sth' is 'accompany him on a walk around NTNU'. The third part is the purpose of the action, so they had a walk in order to test the map functions. Similar usage: 他找我一起吃饭 (He asked me for dinner). 我找她帮我修电脑 (I get her to fix the computer for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 他找白如玉跟他在師大附近走走, 試試地圖好用不好用。

让她(ask her) is implied in this sentence. So, it can be reworded:

> 他找白如玉**让她**跟他在師大附近走走, 試試地圖好用不好用。

他找白如玉: he looks for 白如玉; 跟他: with him; 在師大附近: near/around shida; 走走: have a walk;

Put all pieces together:

> he looks for 白如玉 to/and ask her to have a walk with him around Shida.

You should be aware that sentence order between English and Chinese is quite different sometimes.

Hope this could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Your book is very wordy (to see, to accompany, to try out), or Chinese is quite condensed. I can't see the word 'functions' in there anywhere.

他找白如玉跟他在師大附近走走,
He took Beyonce (freely transliterated!) with him around the neighbourhood of the NTNU,
試試地圖好用不好用。
to check out if the map was any good.